# Navigation dropdown with unfold effect inline

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I am having a problem to order my navigation bar. I want to make navigation bar in horizontal style, but it's like a table now! I found this kind of navigation bar in: http://cssdeck.com/labs/navigation-dropdown-with-flip-effect, but it didn't show how can i make a complete horizontal navigation bar with that effect. How can i fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Navigation Bar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="nav_wrapper" style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block;">
                <div>
                    <ul class="navigation">
                        <a class="main" href="#url">Home</a>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navigation">
                        <a class="main" href="#url">About</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="navigation">
                        <a class="main" href="#url">Navigation &#9660; </a>
                        <li class="n1"><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
                        <li class="n2"><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
                        <li class="n3"><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
                        <li class="n4"><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
                        <li class="n5"><a href="#">item #5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navigation">
                        <a class="main" href="#url">Navigation &#9660;</a>
                        <li class="n1"><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
                        <li class="n2"><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
                        <li class="n3"><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
                        <li class="n4"><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
                        <li class="n5"><a href="#">item #5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

My Css:

body { background: #E9E9E9; }
h2 { text-align: center; color: #CCC; }
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #999;
}



/* NAVIGATION */
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px; 
  height: 40px; 
  margin: 0;
  background: #95C11F;
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 100;
  display:inline-block;
}

.navigation, .navigation a.main {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.navigation:hover, .navigation:hover a.main {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.navigation a.main {
  height: 40px;
  font: bold 15px/40px arial, sans-serif; 
  text-align: center; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #FFF;  
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  display:inline-block;
}



.navigation li { 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 40px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  font: normal 12px/40px arial, sans-serif !important; 
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.navigation li:nth-child(even) { background: #F5F5F5; }
.navigation li:nth-child(odd) { background: #EFEFEF; }

.navigation li.n1 { 
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
}
.navigation li.n2 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
}
.navigation li.n3 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
}
.navigation li.n4 { 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
  transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
}
.navigation li.n5 {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover li {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transition:0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition:0.2s linear 0s;
  transition:0.2s linear 0s;
}
.navigation:hover .n2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.navigation:hover .n3 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.navigation:hover .n4 {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
    .navigation:hover .n5 {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0.8s;
        -o-transition-delay: 0.8s;
        transition-delay: 0.8s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav_wrapper" style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block;">

            <div>
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <a class="main" href="#url">Home  &#9660; </a>
                    <li class="n1"><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
                    <li class="n2"><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
                    <li class="n3"><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
                    <li class="n4"><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
                    <li class="n5"><a href="#">item #5</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <a class="main" href="#url">About &#9660;</a>
                    <li class="n1"><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
                    <li class="n2"><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
                    <li class="n3"><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
                    <li class="n4"><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
                    <li class="n5"><a href="#">item #5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thx, but i wanted to make my About and my Home section free of drop down list!

Answer (score 0):

Do you means this, here is your code

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper" style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block;">

        <div>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <a class="main" href="#url">Home  &#9660; </a>
                <li class="n1"><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
                <li class="n2"><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
                <li class="n3"><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
                <li class="n4"><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
                <li class="n5"><a href="#">item #5</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <a class="main" href="#url">About &#9660;</a>
                <li class="n1"><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
                <li class="n2"><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
                <li class="n3"><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
                <li class="n4"><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
                <li class="n5"><a href="#">item #5</a></li>
            </ul>
          <ul class="navigation">
                <a class="main" href="#url">Contact &#9660;</a>
                <li class="n1"><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
                <li class="n2"><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
                <li class="n3"><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
                <li class="n4"><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
                <li class="n5"><a href="#">item #5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body { background: #E9E9E9; }
h2 { text-align: center; color: #CCC; }
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #999;
}



/* NAVIGATION */
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px; 
  height: 40px; 
  margin: 0;
  background: #95C11F;
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 100;
  display:inline-block;
}

.navigation, .navigation a.main {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.navigation:hover, .navigation:hover a.main {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.navigation a.main {
  height: 40px;
  font: bold 15px/40px arial, sans-serif; 
  text-align: center; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #FFF;  
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  display:inline-block;
}



.navigation li { 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 40px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  font: normal 12px/40px arial, sans-serif !important; 
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.navigation li:nth-child(even) { background: #F5F5F5; }
.navigation li:nth-child(odd) { background: #EFEFEF; }

.navigation li.n1 { 
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
}
.navigation li.n2 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
}
.navigation li.n3 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
}
.navigation li.n4 { 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
  transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
}
.navigation li.n5 {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover li {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transition:0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition:0.2s linear 0s;
  transition:0.2s linear 0s;
}
.navigation:hover .n2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.navigation:hover .n3 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.navigation:hover .n4 {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
    .navigation:hover .n5 {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0.8s;
        -o-transition-delay: 0.8s;
        transition-delay: 0.8s;
    }
```

Comment: But actually i wanted to make my Home and my About section free of drop down list!

Comment: that means, you don't want dropdown list ?

Comment: it means, you just remove the dropdown <li>s

Comment: I meant this! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706665/navigation-bar-animation/26706779#26706779